# Inserted videos not playing on Powerpoint

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I have MacBook Pro, late 2011, running Mountain Lion 10.8.2.

I upgraded to Microsoft Office 2011, and use Powerpoint a lot for presentations. The updated version I'm using is: 14.2.3

The problem is that when I insert videos into a slide, it plays once when I click on the video, but not during a presentation.  Doesn't recognize it as a movie file and only the first frame of the video appears on the page as a photograph.  Very frustrating.

I have a presentation in 4 days and don't want to stop the presentation, go to the desk top, click on the video, show it and then go back to the slides in the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to LINK TO THE VIDEO on the drive. So whenever you click, your media player will open and play the file.

Comment: Thank you. That worked but in my older powerbook, the video I wanted to show had its first frame as a photo on that slide and when I clicked on it then the video started. I wish I could do that now as it looks much better, more elegant. Still, your suggestion is a good stop-gap solution and I appreciate the suggestion.